# How to clear an aray after all it's elemenets have been rendered

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My question is purely related to Angular/Typescript. I've an array whose elements I'm using printing on HTML page. the code is not ready yet. I've something like this:

**Typescript**

```
import { Component, Input, NgZone, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
...

@Component({
    selector: '...',
    templateUrl: '...'
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
    staticKpi = [];
    
    constructor(...) {
        super();
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.initializeComponent();
    }

    private initializeComponent() {            
        let row = []; // For e.g. Apple, Banana, Mango, etc
        ...
        // GET CALL TO AN API TO POPULATE row[]
        ...
        this.staticKpi.push(row); // <--- THIS I WANT TO CLEAR AFTERWARDS
        row=[]; // CLEAR THE ARRAY
    }
}
```

**HTML/Template**

```
<div *ngFor="let element of staticKpi">
    <h2>element</h2>
</div>
```

After `staticKpi` being rendered I want to clear the array so that it is ready for next round of GET call otherwise the next set of elements are just adding upon to the previous set of elements (concatenated). But In my case nothing is displayed. I think it is being cleared as soon as it is populated. Please point out my mistake.

Comment: I tried all the answers but I'm still getting length of `staticKpi` as `0`. It is still being cleared somehow.

Comment: What do you mean by next round of GET call exactly?

Comment: I've a button "Show all". When I click this button it makes a GET request to the backend and fetches all the numeric values called `kpis`. All those values will sit in `row[]`. so when again I press the button, it is just adding up to the previous kpis. By adding I mean I'm getting same kpi many times. So i need to empty the array before clicking on the button.

Comment: I wish I could create a demo but the data is personal and very confidential.

Comment: The method `initializeComponent` is called on "Show all" click only.

Comment: 1. When you make the different GET calls, can you confirm that different parameters are being passed each time. 2. Why doesn't [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65358078/6139527) work? I believe it's doing just what you want.

Comment: @NicholasK, Same URL I've to hit everytime. without any child param. Here it is: `http://localhost:4200/programs/allprograms`

Comment: Yes that's the best solution. But unfortunately i'm not getting anything as soon as I'm doing `row=[]`

Comment: The whole issue is with the last step only i.e. `row=[]`. But I have to have this clear at any cost :-(

Comment: Hard to pin-point without being able to replicate your issue. Can you share the code you've written while trying to subscribe to the API?

Comment: Try creating mock data to share the details..

Comment: Yes. I think that will be the best. I'll try to create a mock. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
*ngFor="let element of staticKpi"
```

iterates over `staticKpi` and displays the template for each element inside of that array;

The elements that are displayed are only the ones that are currently inside of the array, so if your intention is to keep them, you'd need to store the data in a separate array after each call and iterate over that array in the template;

Answer (score 0):

In JS Arrays and Objects keep their references. so if you pass the array among functions and one function edit the array all the references in others functions will be affected. so you need to create a new array.

Change this:

```
 this.staticKpi.push(row);
```

for this :

```
this.staticKpi.push([...row]); // there you are creating a new array
```

now, you can do

```
row = []
```

and the copy of the array sent to staticKpi will keep equal

Comment: I didn't understand that last part you said: "_and the copy of the array sent to staticKpi will keep equal_"

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly, you want this.staticKpi array to have 0 element anytime you call the `initializeComponent method`

```
import { Component, Input, NgZone, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
...

@Component({
    selector: '...',
    templateUrl: '...'
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    staticKpi = [];
    
    constructor() {
         //super(); // There is no need to do this. This component does not extends another component. 
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.initializeComponent();
    }

    private initializeComponent() {  
        // First clean the array
        this.staticKpi = [];  
         
        // Anytime you call initializeComponent method, @var row will always be an empty array
        let row = []; // For e.g. Apple, Banana, Mango, etc
        // Join the arrays together or just assign row to staticKpi
        this.staticKpi = [...this.staticKpi,...row];

    }
}
```