# How to reload a component in Angular without reloading the whole page

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to reload a route but without reloading the entire page. This is not what I want:

```
window.location.reload();
```

I want to reload just the component not the page. This is waht I tried:

1. [Angular: Change the route without reloading](https://medium.com/agilix/change-the-route-without-reloading-in-angular-7a4aa82a8d3e)
2. [Angular: Refetch data on same URL navigation](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/refresh-current-route-in-angular-512a19d58f6e)

Some other random tricks also I tried. Tried following code from this URL:

1. [Angular Basics: Refresh an Angular Component without reloading the same Component](https://dzone.com/articles/refresh-angular-component-without-reload-or-naviga)

   ```
   mySubscription: any;

   constructor() {
     this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute=function() {
       return false;
     }

     this.mySubscription= this.router.events.subscribe((event)=&gt; {
       if(event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
           // Trick the Router into believing it's last link wasn't previously loaded
           this.router.navigated=false;
       }
     })
   }
   ```

But It's not working due to other reasons. I need a solution. Please suggest something else.

Comment: Try invoking the ngOnInit() again

Comment: @NicholasK, hi sir. When `ngOnInit` is re-invoked then array is getting cleared. I checked this already this morning. But I should not be doing so I think. I don't have proper explanation to my tech lead

Comment: Which array is getting cleared?

Comment: Actually all the problem is coming from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65357756/how-to-clear-an-aray-after-all-its-elemenets-have-been-rendered

Answer (score 3):

the skipLocationChange option works for me，try my service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class ReloadRouteService {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
  ) { }

  redirectTo(url: string): void {
    // When skipLocationChange true, navigates without pushing a new state into history.
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/', {skipLocationChange: true}).then(() => {
        this.router.navigate([url]);
    });
  }
}
```